# Acceleration of a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, friction

In the system shown below, the floor is frictionless.

The question of the exercise is as follows: What will be the acceleration of point P?
[image: diagram]

I am a bit confused because I just can't understand the meaning of *acceleration of a point*. Can someone explain?

Comment: It refers to the motion of that particular part of the rope.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question, not asking for homework solution.

Comment: Take a Sharpie pen and place a dot on the string. Watch the dot. What is the observed acceleration?

Answer (score 3):

The diagram is not completely clear, but I think it is meant to convey that there is a fixed length of string/rope that goes around the two pulleys, with one end at $P$ and the other end attached to the left hand object. And the question is asking for the acceleration of the end of the string/rope denoted by $P$ if a $5$N force is applied at $P$.

The other interpretation is that $P$ is a point fixed in space, but that can probably be ruled out because in that case the acceleration of $P$ would be zero.

Comment: Could the answer be $2a_1 + a_2 = a$. It seems the accelerations of the two blocks will algebraically add to give that of $P$.

Comment: @Proscionexium You can certainly express the acceleration $a$ of $P$ in terms of the accelerations $a_1, a_2$ of the left and right hand blocks.  I think the correct expression is $a = 3a_1-2a_2$; consider what happens if either block is fixed in place.

Comment: I think you are right. The upper pulley has 3T forces associated. The lower pulley has 2T with it. Working that way could give your equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 2-degree of freedom system, with two equations of motion, one for each mass. The motion of point **P** is *kinematically* constrained to the 2 DOF, such that if you figure out how much each mass is accelerating, and can figure out the acceleration of the point.

The point has a location defined from the location of the masses, given that the rope has a fixed length. This means that the change in position (velocity) and the change in the change in position (acceleration) are also defined by the same relationship since the position is kinematically fixed *at all times*.

The simplest way is to look at the velocity diagram

[image: fig1]

and recognize that if body **2** is fixed and the velocity of **P** equals twice the velocity of body **1**. On the other hand, if body **1** is fixed, the velocity of **P** equals minus two times the velocity of body **2**. Or in mathematical terms, the kinematic relationship is

$$ v_P = 2 v_1 - 2 v_2 $$

as long as the above remains true, the total length of the rope remains fixed.

So translate the above into acceleration with

$$ a_P = 2 a_1 - 2 a_2 $$

The last step is to do the free-body diagrams for the two masses and write out their equations of motion. These *two* equations of motion are to solved for the two accelerations $a_1$ and $a_2$. Once those two are known, use the above to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the source of confusion: you've read "acceleration at point" as if it were jargon, a term with a special meaning. It's not: there is nothing special about this *point* itself.

Different parts of the machine may move with different velocities and accelerations. The point $P$ simply, well, *points* to the part of the machine the question is about, specifically the upper segment of the rope. Since the rope is this type of problem is by default inelastic (doesn't stretch under force) unless mentioned otherwise, any point on this segment moves identically. I ought to shut up at this *point* to avoid giving hints.